# biblatex keeps omitting one author in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

When I try to do my bibliography with biblatex, it keeps omitting an author from a paper. I set `maxbibnames=99`, still doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{sample2.bib}
 @inbook{seedorf2005,
 author = {Seedorff, Eric and Dilles, John H. and Proffett, Jr John M. and 
 Einaudi, Marco T. and Zurcher, Lukas and Stavast, William J. A. and 
 Johnson, David A. and Barton, Mark D.},
 title = {Porphyry Deposits: Characteristics and Origin of Hypogene Features},
 booktitle = {One Hundredth Anniversary Volume},
 editor = {Hedenquist, Jeffrey W. and Thompson, John F. H. and Goldfarb, Richard J. and Richards, Jeremy P.},
 publisher = {Society of Economic Geologists},
 year = {2005},
 type = {Book Section}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
maxbibnames=99,
style=apa,
sorting=nyt,
url=false, 
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
url=false, 
firstinits=true,
doi=false,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample2.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \citep{seedorf2005}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

This is the final product:[image]

I would like to have the three dots removed before Barton, because there is one more author; but I am not sure whats going on as `maxbibnames` has worked before for me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230452/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` ignores `maxbibnames` because it implements the complicated requirements of the APA manual. For long name lists in the bibliography, APA style wants you to print the first few names, then an ellipsis and finally the last name of the list. In situations like this that can mean that only one name is dropped.

To control this behaviour `biblatex-apa` has the option `apamaxprtauth`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  style=apa,
  apamaxprtauth=99,
  backend=biber,
  natbib=true,
  url=false, 
  doi=false,
  eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{seedorf2005,
  author    = {Seedorff, Eric and Dilles, John H. and Proffett, Jr., John M. and 
               Einaudi, Marco T. and Zurcher, Lukas and Stavast, William J. A. and 
               Johnson, David A. and Barton, Mark D.},
  title     = {Porphyry Deposits: Characteristics and Origin of Hypogene Features},
  booktitle = {One Hundredth Anniversary Volume},
  editor    = {Hedenquist, Jeffrey W. and Thompson, John F. H. and
               Goldfarb, Richard J. and Richards, Jeremy P.},
  publisher = {Society of Economic Geologists},
  year      = {2005},
  type      = {Book Section}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \citep{seedorf2005}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: Seedorff, E., Dilles, J. H., Proffett, J. M., Jr., Einaudi, M. T., Zurcher, L., Stavast, W. J. A., Johnson, D. A. & Barton, M. D. (2005). Porphyry deposits: Characteristics and origin of hypogene features. In J. W. Hedenquist, J. F. H. Thompson, R. J. Goldfarb & J. P. Richards (Eds.), One hundredth anniversary volume. Society of Economic Geologists.]

Comment: Do you know of any way to avoid the same behaviour in natbib / natbibapa?

Comment: @Ben I'm assuming you use `apacite` (the behaviour here is not so much controlled by `natbib`, but rather by the `\bibliographystyle` you use). That behaviour is hard-coded into `apacite.bst` and can only be changed if you modify the `.bst` file, which is a bit inconvenient (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136409/35864). `apacite` implements 6th-edition APA style, if you don't want real APA style, maybe `apacite` is not for you.