# Where to find apacite.bst file to change bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I am trying to find the apacite.bst file in my document in order to create a modified copy of it and thus be able to change my bibliography style (according to the description in the comments of the following link:
[How to change the apacite bibliography style to list all authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136409/how-to-change-the-apacite-bibliography-style-to-list-all-authors) ).
My initial issue is the same as the one described in the link, since I would like to list all authors in the bibliography. However, I am total LaTeX beginner and really confused about where to find the apacite.bst file...

Comment: Run `kpsewhich the apacite.bst` in terminal, and you will get the full path to file `apacite.bst`.

Comment: Or, you can compile a file using `apacite` bib style, and then search for `apacite.bst` in the corresponding `.log` file. This gives you the full path to `apacite.bst` as well.

Answer (score 6):

### With a local TeX distribution

If you have a TeX distribution on your computer, the easiest way to find the location of a file in your distribution is to use the command line command `kpsewhich`.  Open a Terminal window (or equivalent) and type:

```
kpsewhich apacite.bst
```

This should return the full path of the copy of `apacite.bst` which TeX will load. If you don't have a local copy this should be something like (on TeXLive).

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/apacite/apacite.bst
```

You can then open the file in an editor and save a copy in your local `texmf` folder or in your document folder (if you need this for only one document or are working on Overleaf). You should always rename modified files so that the original will not be overridden, since a local copy of the same name will always take precedence over the distribution installed version.

### If using Overleaf

If you are using Overleaf, you need to use a different method for getting the relevant file. The method relies on the fact that your Overleaf project runs latex on a virtual machine, and therefore you can get it copy files to your project folder using the shell escape commands within your source file. Because of the way the file structure works it's still a little convoluted, but it works quite well.

#### Getting the file into Overleaf

In an existing project or a new project, simply add the following line before the `\begin{document}` line:

```
\immediate\write18{cp `kpsewhich apacite.bst` .}
```

What this does is tells the shell to copy the `apacite.bst` file that is being used by Overleaf into your project folder.  You only need to compile with this line once; after it runs you can delete it from your source file altogether.

What this command does is copies `apacite.bst` to your project folder. It will appear in the list of "Other Files and Logs" as in the following image:

[image: overleaf list of aux files]

#### Adding the file to your project so that you can edit it

If you choose this file from the dropdown menu, you will be able to download it to your computer. You can then re-upload it to your project on Overleaf to edit it. It's still better to rename it to something else.  There's no way to directly copy it to your project folder due to the way Overleaf organizes files.

Once you've done this, delete the Cache files.

You can now use your modified copy of the `.bst` file with your Overleaf project.

Thanks to ['yo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002/yo) of Overleaf support for suggesting the direct copying approach.

#### Warning:

This method is safe to use with Overleaf since everything runs in a virtual machine. It's not a good idea to use `\write18` like this if you are using a local distribution; you should just make a copy as described in the first part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Alan, since I am using Overleaf, it is apparently not possible to get the apacite.bst file, if I got it right?

Comment: @stefan.0s Yes it is possible. That's what the second part of my answer says. So download a copy from the link I show, and then upload it with a new name (e.g. `myapalike.bst` ) to your project folder, and then use `\bibliographystyle{myapalike}`.  What you can't do in Overleaf is retrieve the files it uses from Overleaf directly.

Comment: I understood that, but then I will get another citation style than I used before (since I used apacite not apalike)

Comment: @stefan.0s Sorry I misread your question, but the principle is exactly the same. I'll change the link.

Comment: @stefan.0s Actually because of the way `apacite` is distributed on CTAN, it's not trivial to get the `.bst` file.  It will take a bit of time to update the answer appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I have just found the content of the apacite.bst file and copied it into my file!

Answer (score 0):

As an aside that might be helpful to others in the future (since I couldn't find the exact solution)

I came to this link with a similar issue, I was trying to remove `doi:` from `doi: https://doi.org/10.0000/XX-10-1000-1000` in the output pdf, so that it would appear as `https://doi.org/10.0000/XX-10-1000-1000` (just the URL) in Latex using Overleaf.

I followed the instructions @AlanMunn had, and modified line 3894 of `apacite.bst` from

```
\doi{" doi * "}" *
```

to

```
\doi{" doi "}" *
```

By getting rid of the asterisk within the most inner quotations, I was able to get rid of the `doi:` in my output file. (But this also offset some of the output which was undesirable).

Eventually, I simply added, in my `agujournal2019.cls` file, after line 1091:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}
```

This solved the problem. (Other references:
[doi hyperlinks show up as "doi:doi" in my references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482393/doi-hyperlinks-show-up-as-doidoi-in-my-references))

Thanks Alan for the helpful instructions.