# Changing apacite.bst to cite first author when 3 or more authors are listed

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, apa-style, apacite, bst

For 3 or more authors, I want to list the first et al. in the text.

If I use `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` and `\citet` in the text, all works fine, but APA gives me all 4 authors.

If I use `\usepackage{apacite}` and `\shortciteA` in the text, I get ? (?) in the text and acronyms stop working. But the reference appears in the list of references.

I followed this post:

[How to change the apacite bibliography style to list all authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136409/how-to-change-the-apacite-bibliography-style-to-list-all-authors)

And similarly tried to change the apacite.bst file to list 1st author if 3 or more authors are listed (instead of 6 as currently is set up), but without success. Anyone knows how to do it?

I also tried to use `\shortcites{key}\citet{key}` which is specified in the apacite manual (section 4.2 Using natbib for citations) but nothing changed. I don't seem to be able to use apacite for citations such as `\shortcite`. I don't even understand the errors I get when I use `\shortcite`, but Contents / Acronyms stop working.

My LaTex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[margin=2cm] {geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\textsc{} \href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{https://doi.org/#1}}}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}
%\newcommand{\apamaxcitenames}{2}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\textheight}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} 

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}


I want to cite this \citep{kringosEuropeStrongPrimary2013}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{myreferences}


\end{document}
```

myreferences.bib

```
@article{kringosEuropeStrongPrimary2013,
  title = {Europe's {{Strong Primary Care Systems Are Linked To Better Population Health But Also To Higher Health Spending}}},
  author = {Kringos, Dionne S. and Boerma, Wienke and {van der Zee}, Jouke and Groenewegen, Peter},
  year = {2013},
  journal = {Health Affairs},
  volume = {32},
  number = {4},
  pages = {686--694},
  issn = {0278-2715, 1544-5208},
  doi = {10.1377/hlthaff.2012.1242},
  urldate = {2023-03-26},
  langid = {english}
}
```

**Edit:** (function in apacite.bst related to this)

```
FUNCTION {tentative.cite.num.names.field}
{ 'field :=
  field num.names$  'numnames :=
  numnames #3 <
    {   %
        % 1 or 2 names: always cite all of them.
      numnames  'cite.num.names.full  :=
      numnames  'cite.num.names.short :=
    }
    { numnames #6 <
        {   %
            % 3-5 names: cite all of them the first time,
            % only the first name later times
          numnames  'cite.num.names.full  :=
          #1        'cite.num.names.short :=
        }
        {   %
            % 6 or more names: cite only the first name
          #1  'cite.num.names.full  :=
          #1  'cite.num.names.short :=
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the function in apacite.bst highlighted in my question under **Edit:** with the below and it works:

```
FUNCTION {tentative.cite.num.names.field}
{ 'field :=
  field num.names$  'numnames :=
  numnames #3 <
    {   %
        % 1 or 2 names: always cite all of them.
      numnames  'cite.num.names.full  :=
      numnames  'cite.num.names.short :=
    }
    {   %
            % 3 or more names: cite only the first name
          #1  'cite.num.names.full  :=
          #1  'cite.num.names.short :=
    }
  if$
}
```